# Subquery in mysql to use one column for two different results

Tags: mysql

I have a users table and an edits table (showing who performed changes on their own or someone else's profile).
In the edits table, the editor and editee are listed using their userid, which is the unique id in the users table.

I would like to create the query:
Select users.username (the editee), users.username (the editor) from users
inner join edits on users.id = edits.editee_id

How would I create a subquery to pull the editor's name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `users` table twice.

```
SELECT whatever, 
       editor.username AS editor_username, 
       editee.username AS editee_username
  FROM edits
  JOIN users AS editor ON edits.editor_id = editor.id
  JOIN users AS editee ON edits.editee_id = editee.id
```

See what's going on? You use the `users` table twice, and give it a different alias in each use.

Comment: Thanks, Ollie!  This worked perfectly!  I needed to get used to referring to the users table as either editor or editee when I joined two other tables.